# Titanite slab glitch near havel knight Archdragon Peak

Tags: dark-souls-3

So I rushed over to the slab that is guarded by the havel knight as I wanted to grab it and run but was killed when I grabbed it. I went to the item, picked it up and didn't press ok before I died. I then checked my inventory and to my surprise, did not get the slab. I went back from the bonfire and the item wasn't there.

This is pretty upsetting and I would like to know if anyone has experienced anything similar before?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thing like this can happen.

You can try rest at bonfire or restart a game and check Titanite slab location again. If it's not there, then nothing can be done, sorry. Restarting/resting usually helps when some items from NPC drop in unreachable area.

Comment: But it wasn't dropped by havel knight, it was beside have knight and I picked it up but didn't press ok before I died. Will try resetting game and let you know as I already tried sitting at bonfire. Thanks for the information.